# How to instance/copy smoke sim?

Tags: fluid-simulation, smoke-simulation

I made a smoke sim on hanging pot in Sponza scene. Now, I want to make instances of this sim.
I also tried saving Final openvdb baking but when I import it, it give error like failed to load: density_0000.vdb not found.

Answer (score 1):

Got it.
First bake the sim in your specified folder as final.
Then duplicate the object, give it a new smoke quick effect. 
In new domain, set as final and direct it to the specified folder.
Now adjust the domain size to match previuos simulated domain or as you see fit.

Comment: Thanks. I have an animation of cookies baking in an oven and I will use this technique to dupe the steam to all the cookies